# Text on flipswitch is not all visible

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm using `jquerymobile` ..

How come 'Mute' can not be seen on this flip switch? And 'Unmute' is not completely visible either.

Can I setup the flip so all text is visible?

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/0bckxcgm/1/

[image: screenshot]

`html` ..

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-mini ui-btn-left">
        <select name="flip-3" id="snd-switch" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="true">
            <option value="Mute">Mute</option>
            <option value="Unmute">Unmute</option>
        </select>
    </div>
     <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading">Title</h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went with converting the `<select>` to `<input>` and added additional `css` ..

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/0bckxcgm/4/

`html` ..

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-btn-left">
        <input data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-3" id="flip-checkbox-3" data-on-text="Unmute" data-off-text="Mute" data-wrapper-class="custom-size-flipswitch" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
     <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading">Title</h1>

</div>
```

`css` ..

```
/* Custom indentations are needed because the length of custom labels differs from
   the length of the standard labels */
.custom-size-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch .ui-btn.ui-flipswitch-on {
    text-indent: -5.9em;
}
.custom-size-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch .ui-flipswitch-off {
    text-indent: 0.5em;
}
/* Custom widths are needed because the length of custom labels differs from
   the length of the standard labels */
.custom-size-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch {
    width: 8.875em;
}
.custom-size-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch-active {
    padding-left: 7em;
    width: 1.875em;
}
@media (min-width: 28em) {
    // Repeated from rule .ui-flipswitch above
    .ui-field-contain > label + .custom-size-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch {
        width: 1.875em;
    }
}
```